Would Pascal's Wager hold validity if doxastic involuntarism were true?
According to Wikipedia, Pascal's wager is defined as follows:

The wager uses the following logic (excerpts from Pensées, part III, §233):

God is, or God is not. Reason cannot decide between the two alternatives
A Game is being played... where heads or tails will turn up
You must wager (it is not optional)
Let us weigh the gain and the loss in wagering that God is. Let us estimate these two chances. If you gain, you gain all; if you lose, you lose nothing
Wager, then, without hesitation that He is. (...) There is here an infinity of an infinitely happy life to gain, a chance of gain against a finite number of chances of loss, and what you stake is finite. And so our proposition is of infinite force when there is the finite to stake in a game where there are equal risks of gain and of loss, and the infinite to gain.
But some cannot believe. They should then 'at least learn your inability to believe...' and 'Endeavour then to convince' themselves.


On the other hand, the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy defines doxastic involuntarism as follows:

Doxastic voluntarism is the thesis that our beliefs are subject to voluntary control. While there’s some controversy as to what “voluntary control” amounts to (see §1.2), it’s often understood as direct control: the ability to bring about a state of affairs “just like that”, without having to do anything else. Most of us have direct control over, for instance, bringing to mind an image of a pine tree. Can one, in like fashion, voluntarily bring it about that one believes a specific proposition? Doxastic voluntarists hold that, at least in some circumstances—such as when the evidence is ambiguous—we can. Doxastic involuntarists, in contrast, maintain that we cannot. Some involuntarists hold that the concept of belief itself precludes the possibility of believing voluntarily. Others hold that the impossibility of voluntary belief is a contingent psychological fact. Historically, the issue of doxastic voluntarism has been connected to how many think about religious commitment: a prominent view of faith is that it is a voluntary decision to believe. Furthermore, the issue of voluntarism has also been viewed as having bearing on fundamental questions in epistemology. For example, are epistemic norms duties to believe in certain ways? Are there practical or moral reasons to believe? If the answer to either question is “yes”, it seems some measure of voluntary doxastic control is required.

This leads to a philosophical question: If doxastic involuntarism is true and we cannot voluntarily control our beliefs, how could one possibly "endeavor to convince" oneself of God's existence? Does Pascal's wager implicitly assume that doxastic voluntarism is real, allowing for some degree of voluntary belief?

Earlier related question of mine: Can we choose to believe in God?

It seems to boil down to whether acting as-if is adequate. If not, some people apparently are doomed. It sounds somewhat like Calvinism.

Are you suggesting there could be circumstances in which Pascal's Wager did not make sense?
Quite separately since you're asking about one of the main ideas of Western thought, why not use correct English?
It's either 'Would (whatever) make sense if (whatever) was true, or
'Does (whatever) make sense, given that/if/since (whatever) is true…' and hey, Presto! There's your own Answer…
Do you see doxastic involuntarism as true, or not?

Pascal himself gives an explicit answer to the question "what can one possible do to endeavor to convince oneself" (italics below are mine). Note that the whole argument is written as a dialog between Pascal himself (the apologist) and a sceptic:

... So that our argument is of infinite force, if we stake the finite in a game where there are equal chances of gain and loss, and the infinite is the winnings. This is demonstrable, and if men are capable of any truths, this is one.
I confess and admit it. Yet is there no means of seeing the hands at the game? — Yes, the Scripture and the rest, etc.
— Well, but my hands are tied and my mouth is gagged: I am forced to wager and am not free, none can release me, but I am so made that I cannot believe. What then would you have me do?
True. But understand at least your incapacity to believe, since your reason leads you to belief and yet you cannot believe. Labour then to convince yourself, not by increase of the proofs of God, but by the diminution of your passions. You would fain arrive at faith, but know not the way; you would heal yourself of unbelief, and you ask remedies for it. Learn of those who have been bound as you are, but who now stake all that they possess; these are they who know the way you would follow, who are cured of a disease of which you would be cured. Follow the way by which they began, by making believe that they believed, taking the holy water, having masses said,etc. Thus you will naturally be brought to believe, and will lose your acuteness.

The wager argument itself is -- even under the assumption of doxastic voluntarism -- unconvincing. And it is so, even as formal argument since it assumes an actual infinity and infinitesimal probabilities. Pascal lets his sceptic be convinced, however, but the sceptic still asks for further actual evidence, not just a completely abstract wager about infinitesimal probabilities. Pascal points to the traditional givens ("the Scripture"), but the sceptic still counters that they "cannot believe".
The last statement is a clear indication that Pascal himself did not believe in doxastic voluntarism (in the strong sense of directly being able to controls one's belief). Pascal gives as extra path to convince  oneself "the diminuition of the passions", following the example of other faithful, participating in the rituals. Exactly how this would bring about a change is left unspecified here, but as a general point it's not unreasonable to suggest that certain practices might somehow lead to
a change.
All in all, Pascal's wager is a pragmatic argument that rationalizes belief in God for those who already have that belief. Pascal himself seems well aware that as such it's insufficient to fully convince any real sceptic. From a religious (at least from Pascal's Christian apologist) standpoint it also seems insufficient. Note that the whole wager passage starts with a strongly worded claim about the incomprehensibility of God. Only faith can reveal something of the nature of God, according to Pascal:

If there be a God, he is infinitely incomprehensible ... 
Who then will blame Christians for not being able to give a reason for their faith; those who profess a religion for which they cannot give a reason?

So, the wager argument is only introduced "for the sake of argument", so see if "reason" ("the light of nature") can at least give some evidence for God's existence (rather than God's essence).1
Taken everything into account, Pascal is probably best seen as a moderate fideist who believes that faith rest on special experiences -- like his own mystical experience -- that cannot be found or justified by reason alone.
A less abstract pragmatic argument for the benefits of faith is sometimes given today when psychologists or sociologists try to show that believers maintain better personal relations, or are generally more happy, etc. It's undoubtedly true that one of the things that people seek (and sometimes find) in religion is a sense of community, being connected to other people, being part of "something that is bigger than myself", a sense of "higher purpose", "otherwise everything is in vain". But any of those psychological findings have to be taken with a whole big lump of salt. Religions have been and still are one of the major sources of interpersonal and inter-group violence. Especially due to stultified hierarchical organizations where the religious elite (the priests or other leaders) are more concerned with the survival or "good name" of the institution than with any spiritual message. The sexual abuse of children by Roman Catholic priests and the systematic cover up by the hierarchy is only the most notorious example of this.
Reference: The Thoughts of Blaise Pascal

Note 1: The actual wager argument is a bit more subtle and it's almost always represented in a simplified form that doesn't do justice to Pascal's ingenuity. It's really a paradoxical argument, since the basic assumption is that reason doesn't make us incline towards either accepting or rejecting God's existence in any way. But the argument proceeds by trying to show that reason demonstrates a rational person should take the wager. A basic assumption is that we must wager (the sceptic initially claimed that it's best not to wager at all). This assumption is presented without further argument. (Pascal may have considered this to be self-evident.) The chances of gain (infinite happiness) or loss (finite labors) are presented as equal. There is a somewhat confusing suggestion that even if the chance of gain was infinitesimally small, the wager should still be taken because of the infinite gain. (I wonder if Pascal would have suggested this if he had had a clear mathematical concept of limit.) But given the admitted total lack of evidence for or against either of the two options, assuming equal chances for either is really an arbitrary decision. Lacking any further information, in practice, by default we may assign probabilities of 1/2 to both p and not p, but it's equally reasonable to assign any probability to p in that case.

So IIUC, Pascal suggests that the dichotomy "we can successfully decide to believe something" vs. "beliefs are involuntary" is wrong, and there is instead a continuum of possible efforts that may be eventually successful -- perhaps successful enough, because there may even be different intensities or depths of belief?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - Yes, that's how I interpret Pascal's stance. This also happens to be how I personally think of the relations between beliefs, actions, dispositions and evidence. In short: messy relations. In religious belief we then also cannot dismiss his mystical experience -- which leads him to explicitly contrast "the God of the philosophers" with the biblical God. Imo Pascals' fideism makes him more "modern" than Descartes and all the rationalists that came after him.

I even have some sympathy with that idea (that there is a degree of volition in faith). It makes me a bit more sympathetic towards Pascal's wager -- I used to think that hell has a special corner for people who decide to pretend and go through the motions for what is essentially an economic deliberation, i.e. an entirely selfish belief. (And, correspondingly,  I still believe there is a special corner in heaven for outspoken atheists who are truly good and loving and do good things and love.) But if it is not entirely a pretense, then it is less calculating and dishonest.

In the formulation you have quoted from Wikipedia, all it would require from the non-believers is the "endeavour."
So in that formulation, Pascal's wager does not require doxastic voluntarism to be real, but that final step (calling for the endeavour) only makes sense if doxastic voluntarism is not foreclosed.
Sure, if it turns out we are in a state of doxastic involuntarism, then this endeavour will not ultimately produce belief, but the formulation of Pascal's wager that you quote only calls for the endeavour.
You also ask, perhaps more as an expression of incredulity:

If doxastic involuntarism is true and we cannot voluntarily control our beliefs, how could one possibly "endeavor to convince" oneself of God's existence?

There are many things one can endeavour to do that may ultimately turn out to have never been possible. I can endeavour to long jump 12 metres, but it's not happening.
Also, Pascal's wager need not contain that prescriptive step, and can be understood merely as an evaluative tool: it says what belief would be better to hold, rather than a prescriptive approach that would ask some people to do what they cannot.

There are many things one can endeavour to do that may ultimately turn out to have never been possible. I can endeavour to long jump 12 metres, but it's not happening. - But then Pascal's wager's invitation would make as much as sense as endeavoring to unlock super powers, such as being able to fly, being able to instantly teleport to the Moon, being able to read other people's minds, being able to dodge/stop bullets as in the Matrix, etc.

Well, it depends. If genuine belief in the proposition that God exists is necessary for salvation according to some theological framework, the whole approach would be doomed to failure according to that theological framework. It would be like encouraging people to do something impossible that's not going to work anyway. On the other hand, if the theological framework admits the possibility of "acting as if one believes" even if one doesn't as an acceptable path to salvation, it would be fine.
